# How to copy something in a string if I pass it to a function?

Tags: c

I can't copy something in a string after passing it to a function. In the main function I did this:

```
char *s;
function(s);
```

Then in the function I copy something in the string but when I print it in the main it prints `(null)`, why?

Comment: `s` is not initialized, so it is pointing nowhere valid. You need to allocate space for it first.

Comment: @Osiris can I allocate space without using malloc or calloc? Like NULL?

Comment: you'd have to initialize `s` first before passing it to `function`

Comment: @user10967362. You have to allocate memory on the heap (malloc) or stack ([]).

Comment: @user10967362 char s[size];, char a; char *s = &a;, and C++ has the option of the new keyword if you're using that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function like `void function(char*s)` expects a pointer to a correctly allocated object (or NULL to make explicit that nothing valid has been passed). There are several ways of allocating an object, one is `malloc`, another is an object with automatic or static storage duration.

But there is at least one thing that you must not do: pass a pointer that is not initialized; this pointer might point to "somewhere" and yields undefined behaviour then:

```
void function(char*s) {
   if (s != NULL) {  // valid?
      strcpy(s,"Hello world!");
   }
}

int main() {
   char s1[20];  // automatic storage duration
   char s2[] = "some initil value"; // automatic storage duration
   static char s3[30]; // static storage duration
   char *s4 = malloc(30); // dynamic storage duration

   function(s1);
   function(s2);
   function(s3);
   function(s4);
   function(NULL); // explicitly something NOT pointing to a valid object

   free(s4); // deallocate object with dynamic storage duration

   // don't do that:
   char* s5;  // s5 is not initiaized
   function(s5);  // -> undefined behaviour
}
```

Comment: It depends what your function does; if it expects a valid string, e.g. because it prints it out, then you need to initialize `s`, e.g. `char s[100] = ""`.

Comment: The function reads from a file some words with getc and put them in the string

Comment: It will need to terminate the string with the string termination character, i.e. it will have to write something like `s[i] = '\0'` at the end.

Comment: Beware if you don't know how much space is needed for your string before calling the function, your function may have to do the allocation.  At that point, your function signature probably wants to change.

Comment: @Michael Dorgan: agree, yet OP seems to be new to C; I'd not start with two stars :-)